# Javascript drag'n'drop issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I`m currently trying to build my own drag'n'drop app (I'm doing it so I can learn js drag and drop API). So let me explain my issue with a code. There's a jsfiddle below.

[JSFIDDLE HERE!](https://jsfiddle.net/2x37wpfg/)

So as you can see the user is able to drag different shirts in the `<div id="drag-end"></div>` area.

When there's already existing element in this area (first shirt drop) , If I try to drop a new item , I can drop it on the `<div id="drag-end"></div>` area only , and cannot replace if I drag it onto the already existing shirt. Do you have any ideas how to fix that ? I've tried to play with z-indexes in CSS ,but seems that's kinda stupid idea , since it doesn't work. I also will receive any tutorials/ideas for dnd API , because I`m new to it and still trying to do everything myself. Thanks

Comment: Would it be possible to include the [mcve] in the question rather than using an off site resource? Remember, links rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use JavaScript event delegation, you can easily solve this problem. And instead of binding events on document, you should target your div element. And you also don't need to listen to few events. Checkout the fiddle

like:

```
document.getElementById('drag-end').addEventListener('drop'...
```

I've updated the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2x37wpfg/2/)

Comment: Thank you sir , you helped me a lot. But I quite could not understand why ,  even dropping onto the existing image , the new one replace it , because I used "target" and should have used "currentTarget" ?

Comment: I also now noticed , that the function 

if(e.currentTarget.innerHTML.length > 137) {
 newEl.previousSibling.remove();
}

Is not neccessary , it seems the drag and drop API automatically replace the existing item , instead of placing them under each other.

Comment: @Nasco.Chachev Are you saying that you are not sure why is this code working? If this is the case, let me know, I will explain.